# My array isn't being carried over throughout all functions after being created in the initialiser of my class. Whats going wrong?

Tags: java

> this is my declaration

```
public String[] temp;
    public String[] temporary=new String[10];
    public String temp1;
    public Part[] arrayofparts;
    public Part[] largearrayofparrtsr;
    private int numberOfParts=0;
```

> this is where i set up the array

```
Part part=new Part(temporary[0], Double.parseDouble(temporary[1]), Integer.parseInt(temporary[2]));
                addPart(part);
```

> and this is the offending code

```
public void addPart(Part lard) {

    if (numberOfParts==arrayofparts.length);
        expandCapicity(arrayofparts);
    if(numberOfParts<arrayofparts.length);
        arrayofparts[numberOfParts]=lard;
        numberOfParts++;
```

> and I get a null pointer exception because the array isn't recognized in the add part function after it was built.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at PartsInventory.addPart(PartsInventory.java:70)
    at PartsInventory.<init>(PartsInventory.java:57)
    at Main.main(Main.java:33)
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
```

Comment: Which statement throws the exception?  How do you know `expandCapicity()` (sic)  works correctly? You have omitted important information based on your belief of what is happening, when clearly that belief doesn't match reality.

Answer (score 2):

You have never initialized `temporary[0]` or `temporary[1]` or `temporary[2]`.

Unless you actually assign a string to these values, when you call the Part constructor, you are passing null values.

```
Part part=new Part(temporary[0], Double.parseDouble(temporary[1]), Integer.parseInt(temporary[2])); //<-- here they are null
addPart(part);
```

Try something like:

```
temporary[0] = "Part Data 1";
temporary[1] = "2.3";
temporary[2] = "5";
Part part=new Part(temporary[0], Double.parseDouble(temporary[1]), Integer.parseInt(temporary[2])); //<-- Now they are initialized
addPart(part);
```

Comment: temporary is read from a file, and I've used print statements to see if the array is actually being constructed properly and it is it creates the array fine, its accessing that array that's the problem.

Comment: @CalMacconnachie which array is throwing the error? If you mean arrayofparts, note that it is never initialized, so arrayofparts.length would throw a null pointer also

Comment: Part[] arrayofparts=new Part[DEFAULT_SIZE];

Comment: thats the line im using to initialize it

Comment: @CalMacconnachie Can you please add the stacktrace of the error you receive? Edit you question and append it to the bottom. It will greatly help in diagnosing the probblem

Comment: @CalMacconnachie looking at your function addPart, you have short circuited your if statements. You should remove the semicolons after each if and enclose the code to be executed in side curly brackets. I don't know that this is causing your error, but fix this, then see what happens.

Comment: @CalMacconnachie you should also add the code for expandCapicity()